# Beta reduction of S combinator in pure lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

S is defined as `S x y z = x z (y z)`

This suggest that `(y z)` should be evaluated just after `x z` and the the results of `x z` is applied to the results of `(y z)`.

I'm implementing call by value in lambda calculus, I would need to support parenthesis when evaluating this expression right? Does this affect the results? I thought that the order would not matter, so why the parenthesis in `(y z)`?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses matter. Honestly, if you are unclear about how $\lambda$-calculus works, it is going to be rather hard to implement it.

Here is an explicit counter-example:
$$(K S)(K S) = S$$
but
$$K S K S = ((K S) K) S = S S \neq S.$$

I would recommend learning about [parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages), [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and other bits and pieces that make up an implementation of a programming language.

An example of the implementation of the $\lambda$-calculus is available as [`lambda`](http://plzoo.andrej.com/language/lambda.html) at [PL Zoo](http://plzoo.andrej.com/). See [`repl-in-browser`](https://github.com/andrejbauer/repl-in-browser) for an implementation that runs in the browser (an instance of which is [available here](http://www.andrej.com/zapiski/ISRM-PPJ-2019/lambda/)).

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the answer. In fact I do support parentheses. My problem was more at understanding that $x z y z \not\equiv_\beta x z (y z)$ I'll try to get a proof of that to my self

Comment: Application is **defined** to be left-associative, i.e., $A B C = (A B) C$. Thus you are asking whether $x z y z = ((x z) y) z$ is equal to $(x z)(y z)$. The answer is "obviously not" because application is not associative. If that is what you are asking?

Comment: I added an explicit counter-example.

Comment: Woooow, that PLZoo is a Gold mine, thank you so much to sharing!!! I will take a look, I have a lambda calc implemented here https://github.com/dhilst/funcyou/blob/master/lambdac.py. It uses the `fn x => x` syntax for lambda. I will use your implementation as review resource, thank you!!

Comment: yeah, I confused the evaluation semantics with associativity. If I have $PQ$ evaluating P or Q first would not really change the reduction result right? But if I have $PQR$ then this is $(PQ)R$ which is different from $P(QR)$